# The Instrument removeTransformer does not work when in different thread

Tags: java, javaagents

I am trying to learn the Instrument to addTransformer, removeTransformer and reTransformer.

I tried to add transformer, it works well.

when I remove transformer after added transformer as following, it also works well.

```
 public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    ClassFileTransformer transformer = new ClassFileTransformer() {
        public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
            if (!className.contains("Test")) {
                return classfileBuffer;
            }
            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);

            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
            cr.accept(new FieldAdapter(cw, new FieldNode(ASM5, Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE, "hello", Type.getDescriptor(String.class), "test", "first")), 0);
            return cw.toByteArray();
        }
    };

    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer, true);
    instrumentation.removeTransformer(transformer);
  }
```

But it does not work when I tried to remove the transformer in different thread.

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    ClassFileTransformer transformer = new ClassFileTransformer() {
        public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
            if (!className.contains("Test")) {
                return classfileBuffer;
            }
            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);

            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
            cr.accept(new FieldAdapter(cw, new FieldNode(ASM5, Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE, "hello", Type.getDescriptor(String.class), "test", "first")), 0);
            return cw.toByteArray();
        }
    };
    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer, true);

    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemoveTransform(instrumentation, transformer), 3, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
static class RemoveTransform implements Runnable {
    private Instrumentation instrumentation;
    private ClassFileTransformer classFileTransformer;
    public RemoveTransform(Instrumentation instrumentation, ClassFileTransformer classFileTransformer) {
        this.instrumentation = instrumentation;
        this.classFileTransformer = classFileTransformer;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("removed transform.....");
        instrumentation.removeTransformer(classFileTransformer);
    }
}
```

I checked by the output, I am sure the thread for removing transformer executed.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove a transformer, this does not mean that classes that already were transformed at reset to their old state. For this to happen, you have to explicitly retransform already loaded classes. I assume that in your first example, the class in question is loaded after the transformer is removed while this is no longer true in the second example.

Class file transformers can be removed from any thread.

Comment: You means I have to retransform the classes which added inteceptor?

Comment: But It still does not work after I added `instrumentation.retransformClasses(Test.class);` after removeTransformer ? Do you have a demo to share with me?

Comment: It should, probably, you forgot to add something.

Comment: After doing some debug, I found because the TransformManager is null. But I don't konw I forget add what. Could you give me some suggestion.

Comment: I override equals method for the transformer class to avoid that TransformManager is null. But it just does not add transformer for the class which is not loaded before remove transformer. The retransform does not reload the loaded class.

Comment: Maybe a concurrency issue. Your fields are neither final nor volatile.